# Unable to connect Azure-DevOps with Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry

I have created a Build Docker Image task inside DevOps Build Pipeline.
In this task, after selecting the Azure Subscription, the *Azure container registry* list shows *No results Found* message.

Although I have created the ACR in that subscription, I'm unable to connect to it via DevOps Build Pipeline.

Is this issue related to permissions or any other?

Comment: Does the ACR in the same region as your DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you create a [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#create-a-service-principal) for Azure DevOps pipeline?  Once created you can give it the proper role for what you are trying to do.

```
# Assign the desired role to the service principal. Modify the '--role' argument
# value as desired:
# acrpull:     pull only
# acrpush:     push and pull
# owner:       push, pull, and assign roles
az role assignment create --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID --scope $ACR_REGISTRY_ID --role acrpull
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build pipeline, you need to add a login task that uses an existing [Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) before your Docker build and/or push task. The Service Connection has the subscription and the name of the Azure Container Registry where you will be uploading your Docker images.